# Can we attach Azure Premium storage to multiple VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is it's possible to attach the same premium storage to multiple VMs so the files stored in the storage can be access in all of them.

The idea is to have a VM optimized for CPU that will calculate something and write results to the storage and have a low cost VM that will read the results and do other operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if by saying "same" you mean same storage account - yes, you can do that, if by "same" you mean same VHD, no, you cant simultaneously attach same VHD to different VM's.

But you can have Azure Storage Files take on that role, it works like an SMB share, were you can store the results and other nodes will read them. Or you could just create a share on some VM that is supposed to read the results and store the results there.

Either way, its perfectly doable.